# Pros and cons of 5 ANOVAs for 5 DVs instead of 1 MANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, multiple-comparisons, manova

This** study asked subjects to rate musical excerpts along 5 subjective dimensions (valence, tension, energy, consonance, preference); each excerpt had a certain chord type and a certain register.

The authors did 5 separate ANOVAs, one for each DV, to look for the effect of chord type and register on the 5 rating dimensions.

Would it not have been "more correct" to do one MANOVA, given that (as they report) there was moderate correlation between them?

Or is it the case that doing multiple ANOVAs presents its own advantages?

Screenshots below.

** Lahdelma, I., & Eerola, T. (2016). Mild Dissonance Preferred Over Consonance in Single Chord Perception. I-Perception, 7(3), 2041669516655812. http://doi.org/10.1177/2041669516655812

[image]
[image]

Comment: Separate ANOVAs are more specific than one global MANOVA. You run MANOVA to avoid false positives due to multiple testing and to increase the power. When all 5 anovas yield p<0.001 significant effects (as in the table), one does not really need to pursue either of these aims.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the research question is. Multivariate analyses help to answer the question "Is there a main effect on any of these DVs?". So, if there's no theory-driven prediction on any particular DV, it's important to run a MANOVA before running separate ANOVAs to help us interpret our finding. But if the 5 relationships are conceptually distinct, then just running the separate ANOVAs is fine. The problem, I guess, is that it can be difficult to work out if researchers are conjuring up conceptual distinctions post hoc.

Comment: +1 But I would add that when all 5 anovas yield p<0.001 significant effects (as in the table reproduced in the question), then it does not really matter what test to run. There is little danger of false positives due to multiple testing if all 5 tests are significant with p<0.001.

Comment: The correct test to run should not be predicated on what the result ends up being. I mean, it'd be sketchy to say that we *didn't* run corrections for multiple comparisons because if we did, some of the tests were significant. So, the decision to make corrections for multiple comparisons has to begin with theory and intention.

Comment: Excellent point Jon, and thanks to both for your helpful responses